# Can't unset fullscreen mode in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fullscreen, javafx-8

I am using ***primaryStage.setFullScreen(true)*** to put the stage/window into full-screen mode and that works fine.

However, when in full-screen mode and I then use ***primaryStage.setFullScreen(false)***, the stage/window remains in full-screen mode.  In fact, even though the full-screen says that pressing Esc should exit full-screen mode, pressing Escape doesn't achieve this either.

How can I get out of full-screen mode once it has been set?

I am using Java 7 Update 40 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Anyone?  This happens with JDK8 too :-(

Comment: To increase the chance for getting help on this, you should provide the code for the smallest non-working application exposing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            scene = new Scene(root, 400, 450);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());

            loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
            AnchorPane ui = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            root.setCenter(ui);

            loader.getController();

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then setFullscreen(false) and pressing Esc should both work!

EDIT: This works for me(JDK 1.7.0_25-b17)